# insert node at an index: linked list not returning list correctly

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am creating a linked list program, and a function I have created allows a user to insert a new node at any index in the list.

---

The function has two cases, one if the node is to be inserted at the first index in the list (*index == 0)*, and one if the index is not the first index.

The code only ever runs correctly for one of the cases, depending on how I call the function in main.

In main, I have tried to call the function two ways, (value is the node value, and createNode creates the node.)

---

The first is:

```
insertAt(list, createNode(value), index);
```

When I call the function this way, the function runs correctly except, the exception case for *index == 0* does not insert the node at all

---

The second is:

```
list = insertAt(list, createNode(value), index);
```

When implemented this way, the (*index == 0*) case runs correctly, but the other case does not.

In this case, the function returns a modified list without all the nodes before *index*.

Here is the function code:

```
NODE * insertAt(NODE * pList, NODE * pNode, int index)
{
    if (!pList) {
        cout << "error";
    }

    NODE * temp = pList;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        pNode->next = temp;
        temp = pNode;
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
        temp = temp->next;
        }

        pNode->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = pNode;

        return temp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
insertAt(list, createNode(value), index);
```

`list` is passed by value into

```
NODE * insertAt(NODE * pList, NODE * pNode, int index)
```

`pList` is a copy of `list`, so updates to `pList` made inside the function are not reflected in `list`.

By accepting the return value in `list`

```
list = insertAt(list, createNode(value), index);
```

updates `list` with the change.

Unfortunately

```
list = insertAt(list, createNode(value), index);
```

appears to lose the rest of the list because

```
for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
{
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

iterated to find `index` and

```
return temp;
```

sends `index` back to be stored in `list`, leaking the beginning of the list.

This is clearly for educational purposes (and if by some chance it isn't, use `std::list`) so I am uncomfortable providing a full solution.

```
NODE * insertAt(NODE *& pList, NODE * pNode, int index)
```

should get you started down the right path.

Other notes:

Test for end of the list when iterating through it looking for `index` in case the list ends early.

Exit the function as well as printing the error message if `pList` is null. There is no point to continuing with a non-existent list.

Comment: thanks! Yes, was not looking for a full solution. I've just been stuck on this issue all day and was looking for a point in the right direction.